# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'GROUP'

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, visual-web-developer

Hi guys I keep getting this error and I can't figure it out. It works when I run the query in the database tool but not when it's in my Microsoft web dev.

The error i get is:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'GROUP'.

Code:

```
Session["string"] = "answer ='Male'";
Session["count"] = 1;
myCommandSearch = new SqlCommand("SELECT userId FROM UserAnswer WHERE @SEARCHVARIABLES GROUP by userId HAVING COUNT(*) = @VARIABLECOUNT", myConnection);
myCommandSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEARCHVARIABLES", Session["string"]);
myCommandSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VARIABLECOUNT", Session["count"]);
SqlDataReader myReaderSearch = myCommandSearch.ExecuteReader();
```

Thanks in Advance for the help.

Comment: Print the result of myCommandSearch

Comment: You cannot parameterize column names in `Where` clause

Comment: @Prdp if I can't do that then what option do I have to add multiple parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT userId
FROM UserAnswer
WHERE @SEARCHVARIABLES
GROUP by userId
HAVING COUNT(*) = @VARIABLECOUNT;
```

Parameters can be used to replace *literal* values.  They cannot be used to replace:

- Column names
- Table names
- Databases
- Expressions
- Function names
- And anything else that is not a constant

So, `@SEARCHVARIABLES` would seems to be a string.  Let's say it is something like this: `userId IN (1, 2, 3)`.  Then the query would be:

```
SELECT userId
FROM UserAnswer
WHERE 'userId IN (1, 2, 3)'
GROUP by userId
HAVING COUNT(*) = @VARIABLECOUNT;
```

A string is not allowed in that context.  Hence, you are getting an error.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so what options do I have if I want to pass multple parameters in the WHERE clause where it all searches in the same column name "answer"? e.g WHERE answer = 'male' Or answer = 'house' OR answer = '100'. The answer the column that is searched for and the variables searched is always dynamic and the number is always different depending on how many variables the user chooses.

Comment: Thanks, I figured the solution I just concat the variables and the strings together and then pass the whole string as an Sqlcommand and it worked.

Comment: @Tony.C . . . Yes, alas, that is the solution.  You have to "munge" the query together.